# Is there a way to connect ODBC datasource in Knexjs

Tags: odbc, informix, knex.js, adonis.js

1. I have my windows 10 pc with ODBC datasource as my_odbc
2. This will connect to my remote informix server.
3. So for I am using this odbc for my local as well as php website development.
4. I want to use Adonis Js which uses knex.

How to give database connection properties, as to that of mysql, pg, mssql etc.
using odbc data source.
my connection is "DSN=my_odbc;UID=vijayan;PWD=vijayan;"

Comment: Looking at the source, I don't think Knex.js supports the plain ODBC module. There is no dialect for it in the code, so I doubt it will work out of the box

Comment: @J_S yes you are right! I could not find dialect. It tells odbc dialect error! What to do ?

Comment: other than writing your own ODBC dialog, can't see any other way.

Comment: @J_S how to write our own ODBC dialect .?

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can write your own ODBC client. There was some initial work done for it, but nowadays all new dialects should be added as separate npm modules like described in CONTRIBUTING.md https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#i-would-like-to-add-support-for-new-dialect-to-knex-is-it-possible

(I'm not going to copy-paste that boilerplate code here, because it is more probable that knex changes and that linked document changes in compared to knex github getting offline)

Initial work that was done for the support is found here: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/pull/2116